I need a calculated field for button clicks/views in Looker Studio. Is there a way around the inability to mix dimensions and metrics?
I am trying to establish conversion rate for a page with the general equation button clicks/views. Since a filter reading "Event Name = "button_click" would filter out views, I found that I need to create a metric specific to the event type. I found the following formula which seems to partially work for what I need:
Event count* SUM(CASE WHEN Event name = 'button_click' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END)
When I build out a table, with Event Name as the dimension, it seems able to differentiate between the types of events, although the fact that the summary row results in 0 confuses me a little bit: (https://i.sstatic.net/9izAulKN.jpg)
However, if I make the dimension anything other than Event Name, the Button Clicks metric will include every event, including Views, and the summary row will still equal 0:
(https://i.sstatic.net/z6kFQz5n.jpg)
I'm stuck at this point, and any insights that can be offered would be a huge help. Thanks!
I found a SO post that provided the above formula. It seems to work in a certain context, but not in the context that I need. I've worked with generative AI to try to solve the problem as well, but that's just putting me in circles.
